# Show popover with specific option

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 bootstrap popovers on my page. One is visible, the other is not. How can I make a popover visible only if it has a specific option?

For example, here is the *invisible* popover:

```
$('#second').popover({ title: 'Title', content: 'Description...', placement: 'right', delay: { show: 250 }, trigger: 'manual', html: true, container: 'body' });
```

How can I make it visible (through JavaScript/jQuery) by specifically saying "show the popover where the option `html` is equal to `true`?

Comment: The popover is only present in the DOM when it becomes visible. Does the `html` attribute change or are thay static?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create a css class to target instead of using the id? Something like .visible-popover and .invisible-popover then assign accordingly.

Are you able to make a jsFiddle for this? You might get some more help if people can see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what your HTML is, it's hard to offer some thoughts but the documentation is pretty useful with examples here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

As suggested above, you could either use a CSS class and then use jQuery to manipulate how you'd like it shown based on whether that popover has the CSS property.